# Way to connect to paradox db via internet

Tags: delphi

I am a Delphi Developper.

There he has a way to connect to Paradox DB via  internet please?

There are a few years, I developed a general inventory management application (Material Management) for my school: Delphi 7 + paradox.

Our school is the main school and there are secondary schools that are connected to our administratively).
Each school has my software installed in the PC.

The application works fine without any worries. The manager told me that if it was possible to consult the web material in secondary schools. he wants to see the equipment in each school from the application installed in the PC.
Example:
 - see the material from school 1
 - See the equipment of the school 2
 - See equipment school 3
 -  ...
There he has a solution to access the database from each school via the web?

Thanks.

Comment: Never directly connect a database to the internet. It's a security nightmare. Use a REST-interface.

Comment: You could avoid security and other problems accessing a Paradox db over the internet with no app redesign/rewriting v. simply by accessing the application remotely via Citrix if you already have a Citrix server available or using Windows Terminal Services/Remote Desktop server to access the app + db from the secondary schools.  That way, it's mostly just a licensing matter.

Comment: Don't listen to them. There is not much security problems in general exposure of DBMS service to anyone. Anyway, Paradox is not a network service, but a merely a set of flat files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are straightforward ways to do this without modifying your app or db.  One such way (if you don't already have a Citrix server at your main school, which is possible but probably unlikely) is to

- Set up a Windows Remote Desktop (aka RDP) server at your main school, and install the app + database on it.
- At each secondary school, set up one or more Windows machines to use Windows RDP clients to access the app via the RDP server at the main school.  FWIW there is an MS RDP client which runs on Apple Mac OS.

If you set up the RDP access securely (which it is by default on Win7/Win10), this avoids the security and app redesign/redesign issues involved in trying to access a Paradox db over the internet.  By the sound of it you don't want to be rewriting your app at this point, and this is a solution with zero programming/rewriting involved (as long, of course, as the number of RDP clients doesn't exceed how ever many your app has been thoroughly tested for).

Fwiw, I wrote what was essentially a Delphi ISAM DB file-server application, which ran flawlessly for over a decade with 150+ users accessing it via Citrix client connections.  I wouldn't expect any more problems if it had been using MS Terminal Services or RDP, though tbh I've not personally come across a Delphi + Paradox application with that many concurrent users.

An obvious advantage of going the RDP route is that setting up the server + clients ought to be well within the abilities of the typical IT Admin type (though they may well want you to set up the app and db on the server).  You could hand off to them the task of checking the need for MS RDP licences, depending on what licenses your schools already have.

You can check out RDP if you have 2 Win7+ machines on a LAN, using one as the client and one as the server.  However, the client editions of Windows, afaik only support a single RDP session, so you'd need a Windows server to support multiple RDP sessions.

So, maybe the instant reflex to assume that what you're asking requires a programming solution is analogous to the old "man with only hammer sees all problems as nails" syndrome ...

Comment: Thank you very much for you

Comment: Please feel free to "accept" this answer by clicking the tick icon next to the votes on the left.